# Add dynamic controls (PictureBox) with position data read from text file

Tags: c#, visual-studio

I have text file with one line in it. The line looks like this:

```
100 300 200 400 658 487 2636 254 245 527
```

These numbers represent X and Y coordinates of points (first and second are X and Y of point N1, third and fourth are X and Y of point N2,...., ).

I read the file and put it in an array.
My next step is to draw the picture boxes in a container (panel).
The problem is that the panel is only showing the control with last coordinates.

```
private void CreateBlastHole(string[] pointCoordinate)
{
    PictureBox blastHole = new PictureBox();

    blastHole.Height = 15;
    blastHole.Width = 15;
    blastHole.BackColor = Color.Blue;

    for (int i = 0; i < pointCoordinate.Length; i++)
    {
        blastHole.Left = int.Parse(pointCoordinate[i]);
        i = i + 1;
        blastHole.Top = int.Parse(pointCoordinate[i]);

        drawingPanel.Controls.Add(blastHole);
    }

    blastHole.Click += new EventHandler(BlastHole_Click);

    ToolTip tooltip1 = new ToolTip();

    // Set up delays for the tooltip
    tooltip1.AutoPopDelay = 5000;
    tooltip1.InitialDelay = 1000;
    tooltip1.ReshowDelay = 500;

    // Force the tooltip text to be displayed whether or not the form is active.
    tooltip1.ShowAlways = true;

    // Set up the tooltip text for the controls
    int axisX = blastHole.Location.X;
    int axisY = blastHole.Location.Y;
    string coordinates = "Точка N " + blastHole.Name + "X = " + axisX.ToString() + " Y = " + axisY.ToString();
    tooltip1.SetToolTip(blastHole, coordinates);
}

private void BlastHole_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    MessageBox.Show(MousePosition.X.ToString(), MousePosition.Y.ToString());
}

private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{

}

private void openButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    openFileDialogPoints.ShowDialog();
    string name = openFileDialogPoints.FileName;
    File.ReadAllLines(name);
    string[] points = File.ReadAllText(name).Split( );

    CreateBlastHole(points);
}

private void drawingPanel_Paint(object sender, PaintEventArgs e)
{

}

private void buttonDrawHole_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{

}
```

Comment: You are creating only one PictureBox.

Comment: What's in `drawingPanel.Controls` after your `for` loop finishes?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to move your code inside the for-loop, to create more than one `PictureBox`. Currently, you are only creating one instance, reusing it for each `blastHole`.

Try something like this instead:

```
private void CreateBlastHole(string[] pointCoordinate)
{
    for (int i = 0; i < pointCoordinate.Length; i++)
    {
        PictureBox blastHole = new PictureBox();

        blastHole.Height = 15;
        blastHole.Width = 15;
        blastHole.BackColor = Color.Blue;

        blastHole.Left = int.Parse(pointCoordinate[i]);
        i = i + 1;
        blastHole.Top = int.Parse(pointCoordinate[i]);

        drawingPanel.Controls.Add(blastHole);

        blastHole.Click += new EventHandler(BlastHole_Click);

        ToolTip tooltip1 = new ToolTip();

        // Set up delays for the tooltip
        tooltip1.AutoPopDelay = 5000;
        tooltip1.InitialDelay = 1000;
        tooltip1.ReshowDelay = 500;

        // Force the tooltip text to be displayed whether or not the form is active.
        tooltip1.ShowAlways = true;

        // Set up the tooltip text for the controls
        int axisX = blastHole.Location.X;
        int axisY = blastHole.Location.Y;
        string coordinates = "Точка N " + blastHole.Name + "X = " + axisX.ToString() + " Y = " + axisY.ToString();
        tooltip1.SetToolTip(blastHole, coordinates);
    }
}
```